# Custom Node.ForeColor is reset when lost focus

Tags: c#, .net, colors, treeview, multi-select

I'm using this [`TreeViewMS`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2756/C-TreeView-with-multiple-selection) implementation so that the users can have multiselection feature but I found something isn't working properly today. If I set [`TreeNode.ForeColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.forecolor(v=vs.110).aspx) property to say, `Color.Red`, and put focus on that node, its color gets back to default color (Black) soon as I get the mouse out of that node. How do I workaround this? 
I've been looking for an event to set the [`TreeNode.ForeColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.forecolor(v=vs.110).aspx) to my custom one soon as the node lost focus if that node match the needs to change its color. Is there such an event?

Comment: Is HideSelection true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in `TreeViewMS` class. Look at `removePaintFromNodes` method:

```
protected void removePaintFromNodes()
{
    if (m_coll.Count==0) return;

    TreeNode n0 = (TreeNode) m_coll[0];
    Color back = n0.TreeView.BackColor;
    Color fore = n0.TreeView.ForeColor;

    foreach ( TreeNode n in m_coll )
    {
        n.BackColor = back;
        n.ForeColor = fore;
    }
}
```

This method resets the backcolor and the forecolor to the treeview default.

If you remove this method, it will retains the forecolor of the node when you click on another node, but when the node is selected, it will use the default forecolor for selected node.

To fix that, you can draw the node text yourself by doing this:

```
treeViewMS1.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
treeViewMS1.DrawNode += TreeViewMS1_DrawNode;
```

And this:

```
private void TreeViewMS1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, e.Node.NodeFont, e.Bounds, e.Node.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
}
```